# Python set optional variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, init

For a class `User` you can either pass first_name or last_name but not both can be blank to instantiate a user. How to define a class for that

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, fn=None, ln=None):
        self.fn = fn
        self.ln = ln

    def get_name(self):
        name = self.fn + self.ln
        if not name:
            return 'either first name or last name should be present'
        return name
```

Stills it lets us to instantiate user with out first or last name is there a way to make the `User` object only instantiate  if either of first_name or last_name is present

Comment: you have to handle the logic yourself in `__init__`, something like `if not fn and not ln: raise ValueError("must provide at least one name")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, fn='', ln=''):
        if not fn and not ln:
            raise ValueError("must provide at least one name")
        self.fn = fn
        self.ln = ln

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.fn + self.ln
```